# Grape API saving serialized attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, ruby-grape

I'm having a problem to save serialized attribute of my Model. I have a `grape` api with this function in my class.

```
# app/controllers/api/v1/vehicules.rb
module API
  module V1
    class Vehicules < Grape::API
      include API::V1::Defaults
      version 'v1'
      format :json 

      helpers do
        def vehicule_params
          declared(params, include_missing: false)
        end
      end

      resource :vehicules do

        desc "Create a vehicule."
        params do
          requires :user_id, type: String, desc: "Vehicule user id."
          requires :marque, type: String, desc: "Vehicule brand."
        end
        post do
          #authenticate! @todo
          Vehicule.create(vehicule_params)
        end
```

My model is like so

```
class Vehicule < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :marque, JSON
```

When I create a Vehicule in the console like `vehicule = Vehicule.create(user_id: 123, marque: {label: "RENAULT"}` it works fine.

But when I try to send a request : `curl http://localhost:3000/api/v1/vehicules -X POST -d '{"user_id": "123", "marque": {"label": "RENAULT"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"` I have this error message :

```
Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors
marque is invalid, modele is invalid

grape (0.16.1) lib/grape/endpoint.rb:329:in `run_validators'
```

If I send it with `"marque": "{label: RENAULT}"` it works but it's saved in db as `marque: "{label: RENAULT}"` and it should be `marque: {"label"=>"RENAULT"}` as I want `marque['label']` to return `RENAULT`.

How could I send the data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to change in the `grape` controller the type of the attribute.

```
desc "Create a vehicule."
  params do
    requires :user_id, type: Integer, desc: "Vehicule user id."
    requires :marque, type: Hash, desc: "Vehicule brand."
  end
  post do
    #authenticate! @todo
    Vehicule.create(vehicule_params)
  end
```

And to test, you can do like so.

```
test "PUT /api/v1/vehicules/1" do
  put("/api/v1/vehicules/1", {"id" => 1,"user_id" => 1,"marque" => {"label" => "RENAULT"}}, :format => "json")
  assert(200, last_response.status)
  vehicule = Vehicule.find(1)
  assert_equal("RENAULT", vehicule.marque['label'], "La marque devrait être")
end
```